# How do I check if Metamask Wallet is installed in phone using ionic?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-launcher

I am trying to find out if Metamask Wallet App is installed in the phone. This is my code:

```
const { value } = await AppLauncher.canOpenUrl({ url: 'metamask-blockchain-wallet://' });
```

I am testing this in my iOS device. I've also added **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in info.plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>metamask-blockchain-wallet</string>
</array>
```

I'm getting this error:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "metamask-blockchain-wallet://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

If I use change the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** like:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>metamask</string>
</array>
```

I get an error which says

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "metamask-blockchain-wallet://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme metamask-blockchain-wallet"

How do I fix this?

Comment: check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability

Comment: I'm still getting this error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme metamask-blockchain-wallet" @NajamUsSaqib

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the answer after for this problem. The solution was given in the error. I was providing the wrong URL scheme in **canOpenUrl()** and **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**. I just replaced **metamask-blockchain-wallet** with **metamask** and it worked like a charm.

```
const { value } = await AppLauncher.canOpenUrl({ url: 'metamask://' });
```

and in the info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>metamask</string>
</array>
```

(There should be a way for developers to find out the url schemes for the apps that are available on the app store and google play store!)